# JProgressBar in JTable not updating

Tags: java, swing, scala, jtable, jprogressbar

Why don't the progress bars in the following code update and how would I get them to?

```
import java.awt.event.{ActionListener, ActionEvent}
import javax.swing.table.{TableCellRenderer, AbstractTableModel}
import javax.swing.{Timer, JTable, JProgressBar, JFrame}

object TestProgressBar {
  val frame = new JFrame()
  val model = new TestModel()
  val table = new JTable(model)

  class TestModel extends AbstractTableModel {
    def getColumnCount = 4

    def getRowCount = 4

    def getValueAt(y: Int, x: Int) = "%d,%d".format(x, y)

    override def setValueAt(value: Any, row: Int, col: Int) {
      if (col == 0) {
        model.fireTableCellUpdated(row, col);
      }
    }
  }

  class TestCellRenderer extends TableCellRenderer with ActionListener {
    val progressBar = new JProgressBar()
    val timer = new Timer(100, this)

    progressBar.setIndeterminate(true)
    timer.start()

    override def getTableCellRendererComponent(tbl: JTable, value: AnyRef,
                                               isSelected: Boolean,
                                               hasFocus: Boolean,
                                               row: Int, column: Int) = {
      progressBar
    }

    override def actionPerformed(e: ActionEvent) {
      val model = table.getModel
      for (row <- 0 to model.getRowCount) {
        model.setValueAt(0, row, 0)
      }
    }
  }

  def main(args: Array[String]) {
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE)

    table.getColumnModel.getColumn(0).setCellRenderer(new TestCellRenderer())

    frame.add(table)

    frame.pack()
    frame.setVisible(true)
  }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

As @Robin notes, the renderer in only evoked when the model is updated. You need to periodically change the value in the desired row(s). This example uses `javax.swing.Timer`.

```
private class TestCellRenderer implements TableCellRenderer, ActionListener {

    JProgressBar bar = new JProgressBar();

    Timer timer = new Timer(100, this);

    public TestCellRenderer() {
        bar.setIndeterminate(true);
        timer.start();
    }

    @Override
    public Component getTableCellRendererComponent(JTable table,
        Object value, boolean isSelected, boolean hasFocus, int row, int column) {
        return bar;
    }

    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        TableModel model = table.getModel();
        for (int row = 0; row < model.getRowCount(); row++) {
            table.getModel().setValueAt(0, row, 0);
        }
    }
}
```

You may also want to implement `setValueAt()`, as the `AbstractTableModel` implementation is empty:

```
@Override
public void setValueAt(Object aValue, int row, int col) {
    if (col == 1) {
        // update your internal model and notify listeners
        this.fireTableCellUpdated(row, col);
    }
}
```

Addendum: For reference, here's a corresponding Java implementation to complement the Scala.

[image]

Code:

```
import java.awt.Component;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JProgressBar;
import javax.swing.JScrollPane;
import javax.swing.JTable;
import javax.swing.Timer;
import javax.swing.table.AbstractTableModel;
import javax.swing.table.TableCellRenderer;
import javax.swing.table.TableModel;

/**
* @see http://stackoverflow.com/a/10491290/230513
*/
public class TestProgressBar extends JPanel {

    private JTable table = new JTable(new TestModel());
    public TestProgressBar() {
        table.getColumnModel().getColumn(0).setCellRenderer(new TestCellRenderer());
        table.setPreferredScrollableViewportSize(new Dimension(320, 120));
        this.add(new JScrollPane(table));
    }

    private class TestModel extends AbstractTableModel {

        @Override
        public int getRowCount() {
            return 4;
        }

        @Override
        public int getColumnCount() {
            return 4;
        }

        @Override
        public Object getValueAt(int row, int col) {
            return String.valueOf(row) + ", " + String.valueOf(col);
        }

        @Override
        public void setValueAt(Object aValue, int row, int col) {
            // update internal model and notify listeners
            fireTableCellUpdated(row, col);
        }
    }

    private class TestCellRenderer implements TableCellRenderer, ActionListener {

        JProgressBar bar = new JProgressBar();
        Timer timer = new Timer(100, this);

        public TestCellRenderer() {
            bar.setIndeterminate(true);
            timer.start();
        }

        @Override
        public Component getTableCellRendererComponent(JTable table,
            Object value, boolean isSelected, boolean hasFocus, int row, int column) {
            return bar;
        }

        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            TableModel model = table.getModel();
            for (int row = 0; row < model.getRowCount(); row++) {
                table.getModel().setValueAt(0, row, 0);
            }
        }
    }

    private void display() {
        JFrame f = new JFrame("TestProgressBar");
        f.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        f.add(this);
        f.pack();
        f.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        f.setVisible(true);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {

            @Override
            public void run() {
                new TestProgressBar().display();
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: This doesn't make any difference; the progress bars are still frozen.

Comment: It works in Java; you may want to update the Scala example in your question to show your `setValueAt()` implementation. What's the difference between `override def` and `def`?

Comment: I've updated my example. The `override` keyword is like the `@Override` annotation in Java except it's mandatory to avoid ambiguity.

Comment: But not `override def getValueAt`? Your timer's action handler updates column 0, while your `setValueAt()` only fires on column 1.

Comment: getValue must be an implementation rather than being overridden. I've updated my example, the code I was running did have the correct column check (and I even tried it without any at all) and the progress bars still aren't updating.

Comment: Could you put your code somewhere so I can compare it to my Scala version?

Comment: Well, since you helped me learn Scala; I even converted to `AbstractTableModel`. See also [Initial Threads](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/initial.html).

Comment: At least in Java 1.8.0_31 on Ubuntu trusty, the bars are frozen. Also tried different look&feels with same result: http://www.pic-upload.de/view-27921327/TestProgressBar_050.png.html

Comment: No, that's just what `setIndeterminate(true)` looks like; try `setIndeterminate(false)` and incrementing the value with each tick.

Answer (score 2):

Not sure about Scala, but in Swing the component returned by the `TableRenderer` is just used to create a 'stamp'. So the actual component is not contained in the `JTable`, only a stamp of it. Meaning that if you update the component afterwards, this is not reflected in the `JTable.

The main benefit is that you can reuse your component in the renderer. E.g. to render `String`s, you would only need one `JLabel` instance on which you update the text and let the renderer return it.

The [renderers section in the Swing table tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/table.html#editrender) explains this in more detail

Comment: So is there a way around the problem?

Comment: +1 for concept; it should work the same in Scala. I think it just needs something to drive it, for [example](http://stackoverflow.com/a/10491290/230513).

Answer (score 1):

I seem to have solved the problem by overriding the isDisplayable and repaint methods of JProgressBar.

```
import javax.swing.table.{TableCellRenderer, AbstractTableModel}
import javax.swing.{JTable, JProgressBar, JFrame}

object TestProgressBar {
  val frame = new JFrame()
  val model = new TestModel()
  val table = new JTable(model)

  class TestModel extends AbstractTableModel {
    def getColumnCount = 4

    def getRowCount = 4

    def getValueAt(y: Int, x: Int) = "%d,%d".format(x, y)
  }

  class TestCellRenderer extends TableCellRenderer {
    val progressBar = new JProgressBar() {
      override def isDisplayable = true
      override def repaint() { table.repaint() }
    }

    progressBar.setIndeterminate(true)

    override def getTableCellRendererComponent(tbl: JTable, value: AnyRef,
                                               isSelected: Boolean,
                                               hasFocus: Boolean,
                                               row: Int, column: Int) = {
      progressBar
    }
  }

  def main(args: Array[String]) {
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE)

    table.getColumnModel.getColumn(0).setCellRenderer(new TestCellRenderer())

    frame.add(table)

    frame.pack()
    frame.setVisible(true)
  }
}
```

Comment: This should not be required if `setValueAt()` invokes `fireTableCellUpdated()`; I was hoping to see how you call `EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {…})`.

Comment: Unless I'm missing something this seems to be the optimal solution because it does away with the need to have another thread running. I call `invokeLater` like this: https://gist.github.com/2658997

Comment: The limitation of this approach is that it unnecessarily couples the model and view. The `Timer` is just for demonstration purposes; in practice, the availability of new data would drive the progress state change. +1 for the link.