# Specify column-specific TableCellRenderers for a JTable

Tags: java, swing, jtable, tablecellrenderer, tablecolumn

I have a `JTable` with multiple columns that display doubles, some of which are ratios, and others of which are dollar values. I'd like to specify a `TableCellRenderer` to be used for the ratios, and another for the dollar values.

The java tutorials say "To specify that cells in a particular column should use a renderer, you use the `TableColumn` method `setCellRenderer`". This is helpful, but it's unclear to me at what point I ought to call this method on my `TableColumn`s. Is there a standard way of doing this? Should I make a custom `JTable` that does this in its constructor? Or a custom `TableColumnModel`? Ideally I'd like to be able to do this from the custom `TableModel` that I already have, though it seems unlikely that this possible.

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can set a renderer on a column this way:

```
table.getColumnModel().getColumn(0).setCellRenderer(new TableRendererExample());
```

Than you can write your own renderer implementation:

```
  class TableRendererExample extends DefaultTableCellRenderer {
    @Override
    public Component getTableCellRendererComponent(JTable table, Object value, boolean isSelected, boolean hasFocus, int row, int column) {
      Component c = super.getTableCellRendererComponent(table, value, isSelected, hasFocus, row, column);
      if (column == 1) {
        c.setForeground(Color.gray);
      }
      return c;
    }
  }
```

Comment: +1 You beat me to it! There's related example [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/10491290/230513).