# inserting java code from one class to another

Tags: java, swing, debugging, jtable, jprogressbar

So I have an interesting problem. I have an application that I wanted to have progress bars in each cell of the table. To be safe I wrote a stand alone app that does just what I want but now I'm having problems incorporating it into my pre-existing code. Im getting lost on what I need from each file. I.m posting the app table and the progress bar table code. I need to get these two two mesh or to puot it simply I need the progress bar in the app table. Any help appreciated.

application table

```
package gui;

import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.awt.event.MouseAdapter; 
import java.awt.event.MouseEvent;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.OutputStream;
import java.security.AlgorithmParameters;
import java.security.spec.KeySpec;
import javax.crypto.Cipher; 
import javax.crypto.CipherInputStream; 
import javax.crypto.CipherOutputStream; 
import javax.crypto.SecretKey;
import javax.crypto.SecretKeyFactory;
import javax.crypto.spec.IvParameterSpec;
import javax.crypto.spec.PBEKeySpec;
import javax.crypto.spec.SecretKeySpec;
import javax.swing.ImageIcon;
import javax.swing.JFileChooser;
import javax.swing.JMenuItem;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JPopupMenu;
import javax.swing.JScrollPane;
import javax.swing.JTable;
import javax.swing.table.DefaultTableModel;

public class FileTable extends JPanel {

    /**
     * 
     */
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    private JTable table;
    private DefaultTableModel tableModel = 
            new DefaultTableModel(new String[]  
                        {"File",      "Size", "Status" }, 0);
    private File dir;
    private File temp;
    private JPopupMenu popup;
    private String key;
    private PasswordStorage passwordStorage;
    private JFileChooser fileChooser;
    private static String salt = "loquetdeliciouslysalty";
    private static byte[] IV;

    public FileTable() {

        // Set Layout Manager
        setLayout(new BorderLayout());

        // Create Swing Components
        table = new JTable();
        table.setModel(tableModel);
        table.setDropTarget(new TableDnD(table));
        table.setShowGrid(false);
        table.setFillsViewportHeight(true);
        table.getColumnModel().getColumn(0).setPreferredWidth(250);

        passwordStorage = new PasswordStorage();
        fileChooser = new JFileChooser();
        popup = new JPopupMenu();

        JMenuItem removeItem = new JMenuItem("Remove");
        removeItem.setIcon(new ImageIcon("removeMenu.png"));
        popup.add(removeItem);

        // Add Components to pane
        add(new JScrollPane(table), BorderLayout.CENTER);

        table.addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {
            public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e) {
                int row = table.rowAtPoint(e.getPoint());
                table.getSelectionModel().setSelectionInterval(row, row);

                if(e.getButton() == MouseEvent.BUTTON3) {
                    popup.show(table, e.getX(), e.getY());
                }
            }
        });

        removeItem.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
                int row = table.getSelectedRow();
                if(row > -1) {
                    tableModel.removeRow(table.getSelectedRow());
                }
            }
           });
       }

    public boolean isTableEmpty() {

        if(tableModel.getRowCount() == 0) {
            return true;
        }
        else {
            return false;
        }
    }

    public void addFile(File file) {
         tableModel.addRow(
            new Object[]{file, file.length() + " kb",Not Processed"});
    }

    public void removeFile() {
        int[] rows = table.getSelectedRows();

        for(int i = 0; i < rows.length; i++) {
            tableModel.removeRow(rows[i]-i);
        }
    }

    public void clearTable()
    {
        int rowCount = tableModel.getRowCount();

        for(int i = 0; i < rowCount; i++) {
            tableModel.removeRow(0);
        }

        table.removeAll();
    }
}
```

The progress bar table

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Component;
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.beans.PropertyChangeEvent;
import java.beans.PropertyChangeListener;
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;

import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JProgressBar;
import javax.swing.JScrollPane;
import javax.swing.JTable;
import javax.swing.SwingWorker;
import javax.swing.UIManager;
import javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException;
import javax.swing.table.AbstractTableModel;
import javax.swing.table.TableCellRenderer;


public class UpdateTable 
{           
    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {
        new UpdateTable();
    }

    public UpdateTable() 
    {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() 
        {
            @Override
            public void run() 
            {
                try 
                {                                  
                    UIManager.setLookAndFeel(UIManager.getSystemLookAndFeelClassName());
                } catch (ClassNotFoundException | 
                        InstantiationException | IllegalAccessException |    
                                UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
                }

                UpdatableTableModel model = new UpdatableTableModel();
                JTable table = new JTable();
                table.setModel(model);

                table.getColumn("Status").setCellRenderer(new ProgressCellRender());
                JFrame frame = new JFrame();
                frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
                frame.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
                frame.add(new JScrollPane(table));
                frame.pack();
                frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
                frame.setVisible(true);

                FileFinderWorker worker = new FileFinderWorker(model);
                worker.execute();

            }
        });
    }

    public class ProgressCellRender extends JProgressBar implements TableCellRenderer 
    {       
        @Override
        public Component getTableCellRendererComponent(JTable
            table, Object value, boolean isSelected, boolean hasFocus, int row, int column) 
        {
            int progress = 0;
            if (value instanceof Float) 
            {
                progress = Math.round(((Float) value) * 100f);
            } else if (value instanceof Integer) 
            {
                progress = (int) value;
            }
            setValue(progress);
            return this;
        }
    }

    public class RowData
    {       
        private File file;
        private String type;
        private long length;
        private float status;

        public RowData(File file, String type) 
        {
            this.file = file;
            this.type = type;
            this.length = file.length();
            this.status = 0f;
        }

        public File getFile() 
        {
            return file;
        }   

        public long getLength() 
        {
            return length;
        }

        public float getStatus() 
        {
            return status;
        }

        public String getType() 
        {
            return type;
        }

        public void setStatus(float status) 
        {
            this.status = status;
        }
    }

    public class UpdatableTableModel extends AbstractTableModel 
    {
        private List<RowData> rows;
        private Map<File, RowData> mapLookup;

        public UpdatableTableModel() 
        {
            rows = new ArrayList<>(25);
            mapLookup = new HashMap<>(25);
        }

        @Override
        public int getRowCount() 
        {
            return rows.size();
        }

        @Override
        public int getColumnCount() 
        {
            return 4;
        }

        @Override
        public String getColumnName(int column) 
        {
            String name = "??";
            switch (column) {
                case 0:
                    name = "File";
                    break;
                case 1:
                    name = "File Type";
                    break;
                case 2:
                    name = "Size";
                    break;
                case 3:
                    name = "Status";
                    break;
            }
            return name;
        }

        @Override
        public Object getValueAt(int rowIndex, int columnIndex) 
        {
            RowData rowData = rows.get(rowIndex);
            Object value = null;
            switch (columnIndex) 
            {
                case 0:
                    value = rowData.getFile();
                    break;
                case 1:
                    value = rowData.getType();
                    break;
                case 2:
                    value = rowData.getLength();
                    break;
                case 3:
                    value = rowData.getStatus();
                    break;
            }
            return value;
        }

        @Override//new value  //row to change  //column to change
        public void setValueAt(Object aValue, int rowIndex, int columnIndex) 
        {
            RowData rowData = rows.get(rowIndex);
            switch (columnIndex)
            {
                case 3:
                    if (aValue instanceof Float) 
                    {
                        rowData.setStatus((float) aValue);
                    }
                    break;
            }
        }

        public void addFile(File file) 
        {
            RowData rowData = new RowData(file, "A File");
            mapLookup.put(file, rowData);
            rows.add(rowData);
            fireTableRowsInserted(rows.size() - 1, rows.size() - 1);
        }

        protected void updateStatus(File file, int progress) 
        {
            RowData rowData = mapLookup.get(file);
            if (rowData != null) {
                int row = rows.indexOf(rowData);
                float p = (float) progress / 100f;
                setValueAt(p, row, 3);
                fireTableCellUpdated(row, 3);
            }
        }
    }

    public class FileFinderWorker extends SwingWorker<List<File>, File> 
    {
        private UpdatableTableModel model;

        public FileFinderWorker(UpdatableTableModel model) 
        {
            this.model = model;
        }

        @Override
        protected void process(List<File> chunks) //data chunks 
        {
            for (File file : chunks) 
            {
                model.addFile(file);
            }
        }

        @Override
        protected List<File> doInBackground() throws Exception
        {
            String usrHome = "user.home";   // takes the entire home dir
                                                                // user.dir will use working directory
                                                                // (wherever you save your Java shit)
            File files[] = new 
                File(System.getProperty(usrHome)).listFiles();//grabbing all files from directory.
            List<File> lstFiles = new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(files));
            for (File file : lstFiles) 
            {
                publish(file);
            }
            return lstFiles;
        }

        @Override
        protected void done() 
        {
            try {
                List<File> files = get();
                for (File file : files) 
                {
                    new FileReaderWorker(model, file).execute();
                }
            } catch (Exception exp) {
                exp.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }

    public class FileReaderWorker extends SwingWorker<File, File> 
    {
        private File currentFile;
        private UpdatableTableModel model;

        public FileReaderWorker(UpdatableTableModel model, File file) 
        {
            this.currentFile = file;
            this.model = model;

            addPropertyChangeListener(new PropertyChangeListener() 
            {
                @Override
                public void propertyChange(PropertyChangeEvent evt) 
                {
                    if (evt.getPropertyName().equals("progress")) 
                    {
                        FileReaderWorker.this.model.updateStatus(currentFile, (int) evt.getNewValue());
                    }
                }
            });
        }

        @Override
        protected File doInBackground() throws Exception
        {
            if (currentFile.isFile()) 
            {
                setProgress(0);
                long fileLength = currentFile.length();
                BufferedReader reader = null;
                char[] cbuf = new char[1024];//change this if everything loads too fast
                try {                       

                    reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(currentFile));
                    int bytesRead = -1;
                    int totalBytesRead = 0;
                    while ((bytesRead = reader.read(cbuf)) != -1) {
                        totalBytesRead += bytesRead;
                        int progress = (int) Math.round(((double) totalBytesRead / (double) fileLength) *
                                    100d);
                        setProgress(progress);
                        Thread.sleep(25);
                    }
                    setProgress(100);
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                    setProgress(100);
                } finally {
                    try {
                        reader.close();
                    } catch (Exception e) {
                    }
                }
            } else {
                setProgress(100);
            }
            return currentFile;
        }
    }
}
```

progress bar needs to get into application

Comment: See also this previous [Q&A](http://stackoverflow.com/q/13753562/230513) on the same topic.

Comment: @healix : I hope everything is still perfect after the update !!

Answer (score 1):

You should look into AOP [aspectJ](http://www.eclipse.org/aspectj/).

Using this you could do the task